# Pass C++ object contained in a smart pointer to Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, shared-ptr, boost-python

I have a class in C++.
I create an object from this class in my C++ code. I want this object to be accessible in Python.  I use `boost::shared_ptr` to keep the object address.

I've checked out some posts about this but wasn't very helpful.
I think the best way is to make an object in Python namespace after interpreter initialization and then assign my boost shared_ptr to the created object in Python.

I've wrapped my class using `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` in cpp and tested some ways like `namespace["my_module_name_in_python"] = class<"my_class">...` to be able to create an object in python and fill it with the `shared_ptr`.

In summery my question is how's possible to pass a C++ object contained in a `shared_ptr` to python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen that: https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/SimpleExample ?

Comment: @elmo: This does not seem relevant to the question.

Comment: Can you dereference the object and pass it by value?  Can you pass a weak pointer instead?  Do you need python to keep a refcount?

Comment: @Constantinius: it is or I don't understand question. From what I understand question boils down to "how do I expose C++ class to/share object with Python?". And that is all documentation on that wiki.
As for handling pointers there is https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/PointersAndSmartPointers

As for "weird" construction there is make_constructor: https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo#A.22Raw.22_constructor

Comment: If possible, could you please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?  As it stands, I am having problems understanding the actual problem needing to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from the official boost python documentation.

Lets say you have a C++ class that looks like this:

```
class Vec2 {
public:
    Vec2(double, double);
    double length();
    double angle();
};
```

You can derive the Python interface for it like that:

```
object py_vec2 = class_<Vec2>("Vec2", init<double, double>())
    .def_readonly("length", &Point::length)
    .def_readonly("angle", &Point::angle)
)
```

The class definition is now stored in the variable `py_vec2`. Now I can create an instance of said class with:

```
object vec_instance = py_vec2(3.0, 4.0);
```

This instance can now be injected to a Python interpreter. E.g set it into a variable of the `"__main__"` module:

```
object main_module = import("__main__");
object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

main_namespace["vec_instance"] = vec_instance;
```

Comment: Cool! I've tried this though I have a problem with this method too. My class contains different types which forces me to define them too. When you define all these in a BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(<module_name>) everything is fine but with the above mentioned method I don't know how nested objects should be defined. I hope it's been clear.